# flyspell-goto-next-error without running flyspell-buffer first?

Tags: flyspell

I would like to do a sort of `flyspell-goto-next-error` but without first having to run `flyspell-buffer` or `flyspell-region`.

How could this be accomplished?

In other words: keep "`flyspell-buffer`ing" until a spelling error is found and then invoke `flyspell-word` (<kbd>M-$</kbd>).

In my case, I cannot run `ispell-buffer` because I would like to use [`flyspell-babel.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/), which uses Flyspell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(eval-after-load "flyspell"
  '(progn
     (defun flyspell-goto-next-and-popup ( )
       "Goto the next spelling error, popup menu, and stop when the end of buffer is reached."
       (interactive)
       (while (< (point) (point-max))
     (flyspell-goto-next-error)
     (redisplay)
     (flyspell-correct-word-before-point))
       (message "No more spelling errors in buffer.")
       ) 
     ))
(define-key flyspell-mode-map (kbd "C-;") 'flyspell-goto-next-and-popup)
```

Answer (score 2):

The non-flying `ispell-buffer` will search the buffer for errors and then prompt for a correction when it finds one.

Comment: In my case, I cannot run `ispell-buffer` because I would like to use [`flyspell-babel.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/), which uses Flyspell. (Or perhaps there is something similar to [`flyspell-babel.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/) that uses ispell / aspell only?)

Comment: Is there a way to run `ispell-buffer` from the current point?

Comment: @Geremia Do you mean to spell check the word at the point?  `ispell-word` (`M-$`) does that.

Comment: I suppose what I want to do is run ispell, pause it for editing, and then resume it from wherever I happen to have placed the point.